# TCP Client-Server "bad address" error (in C)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Although it seems to be correctly implemented, **it keeps on returning me *ERROR* when I establish a connection using the loopback address**(127.0.0.1).

In addition to a simple TCP Client/Server connection, I have added an additional case:

If the client tries to send data but **finds the connection closed**, it is closed too. I perform it by **checking if received data is equal to 0 (recv)**.

**Given error**:

```
CLIENT:
Welcome to the Client mode
Please, enter the Server's IP Address and Port (eg. 192.128.192.0 1320) 
127.0.0.1 2700
Connected to the server. Now you can send messages
Please, enter a message. Enter "FINISH" if you want to finish the connection
ECHO 
client: connection closed ->: Success
 (1 bytes)Closing the connection 

SERVER:
Hello and welcome to the Server mode
Please, enter the Server's Port (eg. 1320) 
2700
Server socket successfully configured
Server listening [Clients allowed: 5]
server: accept error: Bad address
```

**Client** implementation:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

/**

 struct sockaddr{
     uint8_t sa_len; // struct length
     sa_family_t sa_family; //protocol family: AF_XXX
     char sa_data[8]; //socket addr
 }

 */

//void notConnected();
int main(){

    struct sockaddr_in  serv_addr;  //port + ip_addr
    int                 my_socket, tcp_port;
    char                serv_host_addr[30];

    char                buffer[1024], inbuff[1024];
    int                 io_buffer;

    printf("Welcome to the Client mode\n");

    //CONFIGURING THE CONNECTION
    my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//(2)
    if(my_socket < 0){
        perror("client: socket() error ->");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));//(4)
    printf("Please, enter the Server's IP Address and Port (eg. 192.128.192.0 1320) \n");
    scanf("%s %d", serv_host_addr, &tcp_port);//(1)


    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(tcp_port);
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET,serv_host_addr,&serv_addr.sin_addr) < 1){
        perror("client: inet_pton() error ->");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((connect(my_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) )) < 0)//(5)
    {
        perror("client: connect() error ->");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    //ONCE CONNECTED, START THE SENDING/RECEIVING
    printf("Connected to the server. Now you can send messages\n");
    bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    while(strcmp(buffer, "OK\n") != 0){

        printf("Please, enter a message. Enter \"FINISH\" if you want to finish the connection\n");//(3)
        bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

        io_buffer = send(my_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer),0);//(6)
        if(io_buffer < 0){
            perror("client: send() error ->");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("ECHO %s (%d bytes)", buffer, io_buffer);


        //RECEIVE AND CHECK IF CONNECTION HAS BEEN CLOSED
        io_buffer = recv(my_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0);
        if(io_buffer < 0){
            perror("client: recv() error ->");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if(io_buffer == 0){    //THIS IS SERVER IS CLOSED
            perror("client: connection closed ->");
            break;
        }
        printf("ECHO %s (%d bytes)", buffer, io_buffer);

    }

    printf("Closing the connection \n");
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        printf(". ");
        usleep(500000);
    }
    close(my_socket);
}
```

**Server** implementation:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LISTENQ 5

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in  cli_addr, serv_addr;
    char                buffer[1024];
    int                 serv_socket, cli_socket, clilen, io_buffer;
    int                 tcp_port;

printf("Hello and welcome to the Server mode\n");

//  ASKING FOR PORT NUMBER
    if((serv_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("server: can't open stream socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

printf("Please, enter the Server's Port (eg. 1320) \n");
    scanf("%d", &tcp_port);

//  CONFIGURING THE CONNECTION
    serv_addr.sin_family        = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port          = htons(tcp_port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr   = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

//  ASSIGNING A NAME TO THE SOCKET
    if(bind(serv_socket,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        perror("server: can't assign a name to the socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
printf("Server socket successfully configured\n");

printf("Server listening [Clients allowed: %d]\n", LISTENQ);
    if(listen(serv_socket, LISTENQ) < 0)
    {
        perror("server: fail to listen network");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

//  READ & WRITE STREAM
    while(1){
        //returns a file descriptor for the client
        cli_socket = accept(serv_socket,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,(socklen_t *) sizeof(cli_addr));

        if(cli_socket < 0){
            perror("server: accept error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Server successfully connected to Client\n");

        while(1)
        {

            if ((io_buffer=recv(cli_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0))<0){
                perror("ERROR: recv");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("\"%s\" received from client", buffer);

            if(strcmp(buffer, "FINISH") == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            if ((io_buffer=send(cli_socket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0))!=strlen(buffer)){
                perror("ERROR: send");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }

        strcpy(buffer, "OK");
        if ((io_buffer=send(cli_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) != strlen(buffer)){
            perror("ERROR: send");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("\"OK\" message sent to the Client.\n");
        printf("Closing the connection \n");
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf(". ");
            usleep(500000);
        }
        close(cli_socket);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your "Bad Address" problem still exist after you made the change I suggested on CR?

Comment: This code does not exhibit the problem described, but the original code did.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un indent before each closing brace '}'..  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: this comment: `//  ASSIGNING A NAME TO THE SOCKET` is not correct.  What is actually being done is to 'bind' the socket to a specific port number.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ).   Amongst other things, the variable: `tcp_port` should be declared as `uint16_t` not as `int`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your original question, your accept call looks like this:

```
cli_socket = accept(serv_socket,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                   (socklen_t *) sizeof(cli_addr));
```

This passes "`(socklen_t *) sizeof(cli_addr)`" as the third parameter to accept.  This is expected to be a pointer to the size of the structure.  You should be passing in a pointer to a `socklen_t` containing the size of the structure passed as parameter two.  The size you're currently passing in is being interpreted as an address, which is then causing your program to crash when it is referenced.  The code should look like this:

```
socklen_t cli_addr_size = sizeof(cli_addr);
cli_socket = accept(serv_socket,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                   &cli_addr_size);
```

Comment: `cli_addr_size` should be declared as `socklen_t` (not `socket_t`) but otherwise, good answer